# Prove that a normal subgroup $G$ of $S_4$ with $(12)\in S_4$ is equivalent to the entire group $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Consider a normal subgroup $G$ of $S_4$.

The simple transposition $(12)\in G$. Prove that $G=S_4$.

---

I have already proved that the above case implies that $(12),(23),(34)\in G$. These are all the simple transpositions in $S_4$. I also know that every permutation $\sigma\in S_4$ can be written as a product of the simple transpositions.
Can I use this information to show that $G=S_4$?

Comment: The question I linked to is an abstract duplicate since $$(23)(12)(23)=(13),$$ $$(13)(34)(13)=(14),$$ $$(14)(12)(14)=(24).$$

Comment: @Shaun I can't quite see how that's a duplicate or how your link answers my question? What the link refer to is that every permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of simple transpositions, i.e. the simple transpositions i mentioned generate $S_4$. I already know that and state it as a fact. What I want to know is why $(12),(23),(34)\in G$ implies that $G=S_4$. Obviously the group $\{(12),(23),(34)\} \neq S_4$. What is it about $G$ being normal and $(12),(23),(34)\in G$ that makes $G$ contain every element from $S_4$?

Comment: All said transpositions must be in $G$ by normality. See my comment above.

Comment: Since $G$ is itself a group, it is closed.

Comment: @Shaun but that just implies that every transposition is in G. That doesn't make G equal to $S_4$?. What about all 3 cycles, 4 cycles, i.e. all the permutations being products of the transpositions?

Comment: Each element of $S_4$ is a product of transpositions. Each transposition is in $G$ and $G$ is closed. Therefore, $S_4\subseteq G$. But $G\subseteq S_4$. Thus $G=S_4$.

Comment: @Shaun Oh right, I see what you mean now. Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry it took so long to get it.

Comment: You're welcome! These things take a while to get used to. You're doing fine.